# How to read the request body as byte array?

Tags: protocol-buffers, micronaut

I am trying to read a binary encoded request, the HTTP request body payload as a data encoded using Google Protocol Buffers and I would like to read it as raw  byte array so that I can parse it.

From what I looked and read at the Micronaut documentation and source code the way to do this is to write a **[TypeConverter](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/core/convert/TypeConverter.html)** and use the **[ConversionService](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/core/convert/ConversionService.html)**, but I dont know enough of the mechanics of using these yet to write one.

Comment: The output of Protocol Buffers should already be parsed for you.  That's kind of the whole point of Protocol Buffers.  You shouldn't need to think about this in terms of a byte array to be parsed, unless that is the actual type that Protocol Buffers is transmitting.

Comment: Hi @RobertHarvey may I have not worded correctly, English is not my native language. By parsing I meant to say extract the message payload. Please check this at the https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/1066 . The issue is about how to extract the raw binary  payload .